# Change quantity of product using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a shopping cart and a page that shows all products in a table. I am able to remove products, but I want to be able to change their quantity as well.

My table consists of an input field that you can change the quantity in, when clicking on an 'update' cart button below, I am sending the productname and the quantity to my PHP script. The problem is, it always posts the first product.

Probably because all have the same classname, how can I fix that?

This is what my table looks like:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <div class="kl-title-block clearfix text-left tbk-symbol--line  tbk-icon-pos--after-title">
      <h2 class="tbk__title montserrat fs-34 fw-semibold black winkelmandtitle">Uw Winkelmand</h2>
      <span class="tbk__symbol ">
      <span></span>
      </span>
      <h4 class="tbk__subtitle fs-22 fw-thin">Bent u niets vergeten?</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table carttable">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Verwijder</th>
               <th>Afbeelding</th>
               <th>Product</th>
               <th>Prijs</th>
               <th>Aantal</th>
               <th>Totaal</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td><a href="#" class="remove" id="Bad 13" title="Verwijder dit product">×</a></td>
               <td>
                  <a href="baden/bad-13" class="product-title">
                  <img class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" src="images/defaultimage.jpg" alt="Bad 13" title="Bad 13">
                  </a>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <a href="baden/bad-13" class="product-title">
                  Bad 13
                  </a>
               </td>
               <td>€ 1500</td>
               <td>
                  <div class="quantity">
                     <input type="number" step="1" min="0" name="quantity" id="Bad 13" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty quantityclass text" size="4">
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td>€ 1500</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td><a href="#" class="remove" id="Bad 14" title="Verwijder dit product">×</a></td>
               <td>
                  <a href="baden/bad-14" class="product-title">
                  <img class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" src="images/defaultimage.jpg" alt="Bad 14" title="Bad 14">
                  </a>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <a href="baden/bad-14" class="product-title">
                  Bad 14
                  </a>
               </td>
               <td>€ 800</td>
               <td>
                  <div class="quantity">
                     <input type="number" step="1" min="0" name="quantity" id="Bad 14" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty quantityclass text" size="4">
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td>€ 800</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td><a href="#" class="remove" id="Bad 1" title="Verwijder dit product">×</a></td>
               <td>
                  <a href="baden/bad1" class="product-title">
                  <img class="attachment-shop_thumbnail" src="cms/images/bad.jpg" alt="Bad 1" title="Bad 1">
                  </a>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <a href="baden/bad1" class="product-title">
                  Bad 1
                  </a>
               </td>
               <td>€ 1000</td>
               <td>
                  <div class="quantity">
                     <input type="number" step="1" min="0" name="quantity" id="Bad 1" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty quantityclass text" size="4">
                  </div>
               </td>
               <td>€ 1000</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" class="button updatebutton" name="update_cart" value="Wijzig winkelmand">
   </div>
</div>
```

And this is my jquery script that fires an ajax post.

```
//Wijzig winkelmand met het aantal producten
tpj('.cartsection').on('click', '.updatebutton', function(event) {
  var $edit = tpj('.quantityclass').attr('id'),
  $aantal = tpj('.quantity').find( "input[name='quantity']" ).val(),
  url = 'includes/cartoverzicht.php';

  var posting = tpj.post( url, { edit: $edit, aantal: $aantal} );

  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = tpj( data );
    tpj( "#cartresult" ).empty().append( content );
  });
});
```

The problem is, when I look in network this is always posted no matter what product I clicked:

```
edit:Bad 13
aantal:1
```

How can I fix that?

Can I maybe post all quantities to my php script? What would be the best solution?

Comment: Try to loop over each elements in the cart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting problems because you are only ever grabbing the first selector. You have also designed your API to only send one update when it looks like you want to send the whole updated set.

Below is the way to go if you want to update the quantities for the whole cart.

```
$('.updatebutton').on('click', function(event) {
    var elements = $('.quantity input[name="quantity"]'),
        url = 'includes/cartoverzicht.php',
        postBody = [];
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var element = $(elements[i]);
        postBody.push({
            edit: element.attr('id'),
            aantal: element.val()
        })
    }
    var posting = $.post( url, JSON.stringify(postBody) );
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        var content = $( data );
        $( "#cartresult" ).empty().append( content );
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank you this is what I need! The next step is decoding the json, put it into a php array and merge it with my existing session array, I think I can do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
var $edit = tpj('.quantityclass').attr('id'),
```

you are using a class selector to get the value, it always return the first element value. Instead use `this`

See this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.list').click(function(){
    console.log( $('.list').html() );
  });

  $('.listing').click(function(){
    console.log( $(this).html() );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
First list (It always return the first element value)
</p>
<li class="list">One</li>
<li class="list">Two</li>
<li class="list">Three</li>

<p>
Another List (It always return the clicked element value)
</p>

<li class="listing">One</li>
<li class="listing">Two</li>
<li class="listing">Three</li>
```

Comment: Thank you but I am not clicking multiple buttons, there is only 1 button, to update the entire cart. So what would be the best solution? Maybe post all quantities and id's so I can update the session?

Comment: And what about this: `<input type="number" step="1" min="0" name="quantity" id="Bad 1" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty quantityclass text" size="4">`, here the `quantityclass` is repeated multiple times